# AlertDialog PositiveButton and NegativeButton trouble

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I use below code to show folder list in AlertDialog:

```
ListDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
ListDialog.setTitle("Folder List");
ListView folder = new ListView(MyActivity.this);
//scan folder
folder.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
//scan sub-folder
});
ListDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//do something
}
});
ListDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//back
}
});
```

I want to make the AlertDialog's NegativeButton always show, and the AlertDialog's PositiveButton only show while the list item number is 0.
How to arrive it?

Comment: You will have to create a custom dialog or use two different alerts for your cases.

Comment: i had past code sample see that,, it work fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it work fine..

Call Dialog Method Like this,,,,

```
dialog_message("Dialog msg");


public void dialog_message(String msg) 
    {
          final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BottomMenu_Event.this).create();

              alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
              alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
              alertDialog.setMessage(msg);

              alertDialog.setButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
              {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
               {
                  //Your Code....           
               }
              });

              alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
              {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
               {       

                   alertDialog.dismiss();

               }
              });

              alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put condition, if your list item gives 0 then then allow to show positive button else not.

I tried using flag when its not true its wont show positive button else it will show both.

Below is the code

```
AlertDialog.Builder ListDialog;
     AlertDialog contactMessage;
    flag=true;
    ListDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdvancedListViewActivity.this);
    ListDialog.setTitle("Folder List");
    if(flag!=true){
    ListDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //do something
    }
    });
    }
    ListDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //back
    }
    });

    contactMessage = ListDialog.create();
    contactMessage.show();
```

Same thing you can also do, check condition while your list item is not zero avoid positive button else show it.

Comment: it only check first time. if scan sub-folder and show it does not check again.